# Robot Markov Chain

Tags: probability

So there is a robot in a room with n coins on the ground. The robot goes around to each coin once and if the coin shows heads he turns it to tails and moves to another coin. If the coin shows tails he flips it. Can this be represented as a markov chain? How?

Comment: Does it go to the coins in order? If it goes to each coin in succession and always flips a coin no matter what, then there really isn't any randomness in the evolution of the process. But if somehow it moves around the room erratically then you have a more interesting situation.

Comment: No order. Picks coins completely at random until they are all flipped

Comment: No he turns it to tails then moves to another coin

Comment: Until they are all flipped to...what? Can he come back to a coin more than once?

Comment: I mean until he has been to all the coins not flipped

Comment: But can he come back to a coin? If he does, do you have to wait until all the coins have now wound up flipped, or is it just until each one has *been* flipped? This is an important distinction: one way the state can be taken to just be the status of the coins, the other way needs twice as many states to keep track of whether a coin has been flipped at least once.

Comment: No he cant go back to a coin

Comment: But he randomly chooses from the coins which have been flipped. OK. But now what data do you want to extract from this process? There are different state spaces to use to describe this situation, some of which are Markov (e.g. the state is the set of coins which have already been visited, so that there are $2^n$ states) and others of which are not (e.g. the state is the coin which was just visited). A good choice of state space depends on what you want to get out of the problem.

Comment: Trying to find the probability of heads and then it just says represent as a markov chain